# How to bookmark and retrieve bookmarks in android java

Tags: java, android, androidpdfviewer

Well I am using pdf viewer by bartsek but when I try to retrieve bookmarks using the bookmark function it gives me wierd characters
Here is the code

```
pdfview.getTableofContents.toString()
```

[Wierd characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kht3.jpg)

How can I achieve this

I want a list of bookmarks and a way of bookmarking pages
I have no idea about it

Comment: @KJ so please explain more about bookmarks cause they are getting more wierd

Comment: Well thanks for the explanation and help @KJ so how do we extract bookmarks and how do we make them using pdfviewer lib

Comment: I have seen it that's what I wanted so how am I getting them in java@KJ

Comment: Well I had gotten them but I cant insert them into the dialog

Comment: If I use log.i it printed them but I I use a variable it says null